# Restore Skype view with my correspondent's video in full screen and my video in a small window

Tags: windows-10, video, skype

With the new Skype for Windows10 (v8.29.0.50), Microsoft has introduced an annoying feature: during video calls, the screen is split in half with my video on the right side and my correspondent's video on the left side.

How to restore the default view, with my correspondent's video in full screen and my video in a small resizable window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following way:

1. Click the video of you.
2. This makes a small handle appear at the top-left corner of the video preview.
3. Drag the handle to adjust the video size. The preview video window will get larger as you drag outward. To reduce the size of the preview video, drag the handle back down and to the right until it looks the way you want it.

You can resize the video whether or not you’re in full screen mode.

If you want to move the video of you to another location, just click and drag it to a different area.

[image]

For details we can refer to: [How to Resize a Skype Video Chat on PC or Mac](https://www.wikihow.com/Resize-a-Skype-Video-Chat-on-PC-or-Mac)